# Create a table in mysql

Tags: mysql, sql

Here is the mysql code. I can't find the error here. when I execute this bunch of code it shows syntax error.

```
 CREATE TABLE Movie(
-> title            varchar(100),
-> year             int,
-> length           int,
-> inColor          BIT(1),
-> studioName       varchar(50),
-> producerC#       int,
-> PRIMARY KEY      ('title'));
```

Comment: The `title` column should not be between single quotes.

Comment: I would recommend removing the `#` from the column `producerC#`, it's a non standard character and may cause problems further down the line.

Answer (score 2):

Try this. You have quotes in the primary key!

```
CREATE TABLE `movie` (
  `title` VARCHAR(100),
  `year` INT(11),
  `length` INT(11),
  `inColor` BIT(1),
  `studioName` VARCHAR(50),
  `producerC#` INT(11),
  PRIMARY KEY (`title`)
)
```

Comment: +1 to counterbalance -1. This answer is clearer than the other as it explains where the problem comes from.

Answer (score 1):

You can use below query to create table:

```
CREATE TABLE Movie(
title VARCHAR(100) PRIMARY KEY,
year INT,
length INT,
inColor BIT(1),
studioName VARCHAR(50),
producerC# int
)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
CREATE TABLE `movie` (
  `title` VARCHAR(100),
  `year` INT(11),
  `length` INT(11),
  `inColor` BIT(1),
  `studioName` VARCHAR(50),
  `producerC#` INT(11),
  PRIMARY KEY (`title`)
)
```